# What is the best practice to follow in order to use Python to call functions from inside a Rust program?

Tags: python, rust, ffi, pyo3

I want to implement a system which consists of a Python UI and some Rust datastore and functions. 
The user executes the python code which in turn executes the Rust program in a subprocess.
I want the Rust program to run in the background, waiting to exchange variables or function calls with the Python UI (for example every time a button is pressed).

My obstacles are:

1. I have tried to make a simple Rust FFI library that can be invoked with ctypes from Python but I don't know how this library will be able to communicate with the compiled rust program that is running on the background.
2. Another approach is to use PyO3 to make a python module using rust. But again I cannot understand how this will cooperate with the rust program to exchange data

Comment: [The Rust FFI Omnibus](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/)

Answer (score 1):

Your Rust background process will need to expose some kind of RPC mechanism such as [jsonrpc](https://crates.io/crates/json_rpc) or [msgpack-rpc](https://crates.io/crates/rmp-rpc).

Then any other application can call into your background process using the same RPC mechanism. For example for Python, there are libraries for [jsonrpc](https://pypi.org/search/?q=jsonrpc) and [msgpack-rpc](https://pypi.org/search/?q=msgpack+rpc).